# Is there a way to initialize object, call its method, then pass it as function argument, in just the function call scope?

Tags: c++, function, object, pass-by-reference, one-liner

Is there a way to initialize an object, call a few of its method (it is not possible to just construct the object to be in the needed state), then pass it as an argument to a function, and possibly one-liner, just in the calling scope? Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
void log(const std::ostringstream& obj) {
    std::cout<<obj.str();
    //Do something meaningful with obj that doesn't modify it
}
void gol(const std::string& obj) {
    std::cout<<obj;
    //Do something meaningful with obj that doesn't modify it
} 
int main() {
    log(std::ostringstream oss << "Foo" << 123 << 'B');
    gol(std::string str .append("Foo").append(std::to_string(123)).append("Bar"));
}
```

By "in the calling scope",  I mean that the object "oss" is automatically destroyed after "log" returns. The same goes for "str".

I could do it like this:

```
int main() {
     {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << "Foo" << 123 << 'B';
        log(oss);
     }
     {
        std::string str;
        str.append("Foo").append(std::to_string(123)).append("Bar"));
        gol(str);
     }
}
```

But then it's not really one-liner anymore.

Comment: `log(std::ostringstream() << "Foo" << 123 << 'B');`?

Comment: You can also make a `class Log` that creates a `std::ostringstream` in the constructor, provides `operator<<` and does the meaningful in `~Log()`. You then call `Log() << "Foo" << 123 << 'B';`

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I forgot to mention I need to call methods in general (those that return reference to the object (return *this) so I can chain)

Comment: That still works with a Log object, you just have to have `template <typename T> Log & append(const T &t) { str.append(std::to_string(t)); return *this; }` for that example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
void log(const std::ostringstream& obj) {
    std::cout<<obj.str();
    //Do something meaningful with obj that doesn't modify it
}
void gol(const std::string& obj) {
    std::cout<<obj;
    //Do something meaningful with obj that doesn't modify it
} 
int main() {
    log(std::ostringstream{} << "Foo" << 123 << 'B');
    gol(std::string{}.append("Foo").append(std::to_string(123)).append("Bar"));
}
```

Though, I am not aware of a way to give it a name, call methods, and pass it to another function, all in the same expression.

In general, trying to squeeze as much code into a single line is not something that is actually desirable.

Comment: Doesn't compile, "error: invalid initialization", g++ 8.1.0, -std=c++17

Comment: @GiBhu 8.1.0 is rather ancient. Are you sure it even has full C++11 support?

Comment: I installed using MinGW setup, it's the lastest version on the web setup even now.

Comment: perhaps try `std::ostringstream()`

Comment: the same error, "invalid initialization"

Comment: @GiBhu interesting. I don't understand what changed (works with newer version: https://godbolt.org/z/EoPhrfPo5). I'll post an update once I found out

Comment: gcc 11.1 has issue, but not gcc 11.2 [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4cMrxo8Wd).

Comment: works with user class, and `std::string` works too. I don't know why the compiler not recognizes `std::ostringstream` though.

Comment: `std::ostringstream` does not have a *default constructor* prior to C++11.  Try `std::ostringstream("")` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the issue is with C++17 and gcc earlier than 11.2. I tried to find some `<<` overload whose return type changed or has different overloads but so far without luck. I am starting to believe that it was a bug in gcc